# Prevent Empty Gridview data from populating "&nbsp;" into textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this code that populates a textbox based on a cell in the selected row of a gridview

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtComment.Text = row.Cells[14].Text.Trim();

    }
```

It displays `&nbsp;` in the txtComment textbox if Cell[14] has no data.

Is there a way to prevent the `&nbsp;` from appearing when there is no data in the cell of the selected row?

---

Edit
I tried this and it didn't work

```
if (row.Cells[14].Text.Trim().Length > 1)
{
    txtComment.Text = row.Cells[14].Text.Trim();
}
else
{
    txtComment.Text = row.Cells[14].Text = "";
}
```

===================================================================

This worked

```
if (row.Cells[14].Text.Trim()!="&nbsp;")
{
    txtComment.Text = row.Cells[14].Text.Trim();
}
else
{
    txtComment.Text = row.Cells[14].Text = "";
}
```

Comment: have you tried `row.Cells[14].Text = string.Empty;` or `= "";`?

Comment: I tried both =string.Empty; and =""; and i still got the &nbsp

Answer (score 14):

I also had a problem like this one, and i found this useful too:

```
txtComment.Text = row.Cells[14].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
```

i hope it can help you :)

Answer (score 12):

Use    NullDisplayText=" "

```
     <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Name" NullDisplayText=" "/>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to write any code, just add HtmlEncode="false" to the Boundfield.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
Server.HtmlDecode()
```

For example:

```
txtComment.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[14].Text);
```

It handles not only spaces, but also other conversions like ampersands(&) and etc.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you're accessing the Text property of the HTML cell rather than the data column.  The gridview needs to display `&nbsp;` in an empty table cell in order for that table cell to still be visible when rendered to some browsers.  This is because of HTML and doesn't have anything to do with your data or code;

What you should be doing is something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow myRow = (DataRow)GridView1.SelectedRow.DataItem;
    txtComment.Text = myRow[14];
}
```

The format for accessing the data item property is going to be a little different based on what that DataItem actually is, you can cast it to the type of object that fits your data source and then access its properties accordingly.

EDIT: I changed the example code to demonstrate casting the DataItem property to a DataRow object.  You need to cast it to whatever type you are feeding as a DataSource.  I hope this is more clear.

Comment: I'm getting this error message when I try it  "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"

Comment: @JoshuaSlocum: See my edits above, you need to cast the DataItem to whatever type of object is being used as the data source.